# Sinning from Joy

Tags: bentching

Berachot 46 tells us that the guest blesses his host: "may no thought of sin, iniquity, or transgression stand before him or before us
from now and for evermore".

I remember seeing that this is because joy from party at times can lead to sin - so we therefore insert this blessing.

Have anyone seen this anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Sefer Imrei Shefer by Rav Shimon Deutsch](https://books.google.com/books/about/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%A8.html?id=NvoOtwAACAAJ), a Talmid of the Chassam Sofer, says this:

[image: Imrei Shefer]

Comment: Would you consider writing (at least a short) summary of it?

Comment: The problem is that Birkat HaMoazon is recited "after" the meal so why would this help?

Comment: @AviM That's a good point. I'm going to have to think about that. My first impression is that its to avoid a וישמן ישורון ויבעט type issue which would arise after the meal - that the meal put you in the mood for sin and then you'll go from the meal and do a sin. I'm curious if anyone else has any other answers.

Comment: I think you are right - he does write: מתוך אכילתו ״שאכל״ - he's clearly talking about after the meal.